# Put ArrayList in ContentValues

Tags: android, arraylist, android-contentprovider, couchbase, content-values

I'm using couchbaselite in Android, I want to use ContentProvider and ContentValues to insert Documents in my DB. One property of my documents is an ArrayList, but with the ConentValues I can't put directly an ArrayList. Here my code:

```
ContentValues valuesTour = new ContentValues();
valuesTour.put(DBFields.COLUMN_PROGRESS_PERC,completionPercentage);
valuesTour.put(DBFields.COLUMN_STEPS, new ArrayList()); //here I need to put an ArrayList
update(DBFields.CONTENT_URI, valuesTour, 1234, null);
```

Is there a workaround to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put arrays directly in a database. In your code, you are essentially saving the address of the array which is useless. An easy solution would be to convert the array to a string either using your own implementation of toString() or using a third party library (i.e. Gson).